# Kendo UI validation messages localization

Tags: kendo-ui

I've got a small project which uses Kendo UI Scheduler. I've created a custom localization like was written in Telerik's instructions by creating a custom file **kendo.messages.'language'.js** file

But I'm still getting validation errors in scheduler in default en-GB localization.

For example

**End date should be greater then or equal to the start date**

Is there any way to localize them too?

Answer (score 0):

It worked correctly for bg-BG messages on Kenedo Scheduler localization [demo](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/scheduler/localization). It is controlled by the dateCompare property of kendo.ui.Validator that can be seen on [this line](https://github.com/telerik/kendo-ui-core/blob/54b55ab860e1aa83fe86a104981f004771276217/src/messages/kendo.messages.bg-BG.js#L14) in the messages.bg-BG.js file.